# Threads in python are using the same variable it seems

Tags: python, multithreading, file-upload, ftp

I built a class that watches for changes in a directory and upload them to a server, it is working fine for **one** dir. However, i had the idea to use the threading module from python to actually watch more than one directory. But, i am getting confused, since when i change a file in one location, it uploads just fine, but then the OTHER location starts uploading all it's files. I think it's because somehow the threads are sharing the same variable or something, but still it's impossible because each directory has it's own instance of the class working specifically for it.

Here's some code:

```
import os, ftplib, time
from threading import Thread


class FTPSync(Thread):

    local_root = ''
    remote_root = ''
    host = ''
    user = ''
    password = ''
    content = {
        'previous': [],
        'current': []
    }
    ignore = []
    rest = 0.5
    files = []
    cwd = ''
    watching = True

    def __init__(self, local_root='', remote_root='', config={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.local_root = local_root if local_root != '' else os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
        self.remote_root = remote_root
        self.ignore = config['ignore'] if 'ignore' in config else []
        self.rest = config['rest'] if 'rest' in config else 0.5
        self.host, self.user, self.password = config['host'], config['user'], config['password']
        self.content['previous'] = self.read_dir(self.local_root)

    # Connect and reconnect to the server
    def connect(self, reconnect=False):
        print "Connecting..."
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP(self.host)
        self.ftp.login(self.user, self.password)
        print "Welcome message from server:\n"
        print self.ftp.getwelcome()
        if not reconnect:
            self.cwd = self.remote_root
        self.ftp.cwd(self.cwd)

    # Start watching for local changes
    def watch(self):
        self.connect()
        while self.watching:
            self.files = []
            self.content['current'] = self.read_dir(self.local_root)
            diff = [f for f in self.content['current'] if f not in self.content['previous']]
            if len(diff) > 0:
                self.stor(diff)
                self.content['previous'] = self.content['current']
                diff = []
            time.sleep(self.rest)

    # Read a directory and its contents recursively
    def read_dir(self, dir_name, return_value=True):
        reading = os.listdir(dir_name)
        file_content = None
        for i in range(len(reading)):
            d = self._local_abspath(dir_name, reading[i])
            is_dir = os.path.isdir(d)
            file_content = open(d).read() if not is_dir else None
            offset = d.replace(self.local_root, '').replace(reading[i], '')
            if is_dir and reading[i] not in self.ignore:
                self.read_dir(d, return_value=False)
            elif not is_dir:
                info = {"name": reading[i], "content": file_content, "local_path": d, "offset": offset}
                self.files.append(info)
        if (return_value):
            return self.files
        pass

    # Here we go
    def run(self):
        self.watch()

    # Store (STOR) the files in the server
    def stor(self, files):
        nav = ''
        try:
            for f in files:
                if self._server_abspath(f['offset']) != self.cwd:
                    nav = self._server_abspath(f['offset'])
                    self.ftp.cwd(nav)
                mode = ''
                if f['name'].split('.')[-1:][0] in ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'] or os.path.getsize(f['local_path']) > 8190:
                    mode = 'binary'
                    self.ftp.storbinary('STOR {!s}'.format(f['name']), open(f['local_path']))
                else:
                    mode = 'ascii'
                    self.ftp.storlines('STOR {!s}'.format(f['name']), open(f['local_path']))
                self.cwd = self._server_abspath(f['offset'])
                print "Stored %s in %s mode" % (f['name'], mode)

        # The connection has timed out
        except ftplib.error_temp:
            self.connect(reconnect=True)
            self.stor(files)

        # A new file has been created inside a folder that does not exist in the server
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            self.ftp.mkd(nav)
            self.stor(files)

        # A new folder has been created locally, but we'll wait to update this on the server
        # when there's some content inside of it and throw us a ftplib.error_perm error, so here it'll just pass
        except IOError:
            pass

    # Return the absolute path in the server
    def _server_abspath(self, path):
        return self.remote_root + '/' + path.replace('\\', '/')

    # Return the absolute path locally
    def _local_abspath(self, dn, fn):
        return (dn +'\\'+ fn) if not dn[-1:]=='\\' else dn + fn


def start(local_root='', remote_root='', config={}):
    instance = FTPSync(local_root, remote_root, config)
    instance.start()
    return instance
```

And this is how i use the class:

```
import ftpsync

config = {
    'host': 'ftp.myhost.com',
    'user': '****',
    'password': '****',
    'ignore': ['.git']
}

ftpsync.start(remote_root='/www/tst', config=config)
ftpsync.start(local_root='C:\\pygames', remote_root='/www/tst', config=config)
```

I would like to remember that it works fine for **ONE** directory.

Comment: Buddy, try to fix identation. There is no way to understand where starts or ends your class.

Comment: the identation is fixed

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717954/python-threaded-reading-from-multiple-files) before

Comment: Then, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776293/read-txt-file-with-multi-threaded-in-python) :-)

Comment: I looked these questions, but still no idea where i would use them in my code. I should abandon threads? Where should i use multiprocessing? Reading files, or for each directory?

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I realized I had to use processes. I came back here in case someone finds it useful.

So basically, with threads you're just running two or more concurrent things at once, but they all share the same address space and memory, and can cause some unwanted things by having the same context and interacting with each other.

Now with processes, every process is independent from one another, so they all have resources reserved for each one of them. This won't let them share variables and stuff.